# T-SQL: How to reverse values in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, I'm trying to find the easiest way to make `"Test One"` become `"One, Test"`.

Basically switch the " " and ", " if there are just 2 words in a column with a space between them.

For example:

```
Before             After
Test One           One, Test
Test Two One       Test Two One
Test, Three        Test, Three
```

Comment: This is something likely to be easier to do in application code using regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
select col Before,
  case 
    when col like '%,%' then col 
    when len(replace(col, ' ', '')) = len(col) -1 
      then reverse(substring(reverse(col), 1, charindex(' ', reverse(col))-1))+', '+substring(col, 1, charindex(' ', col)-1)
    else col
  end  After
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a882a/11). The result is:

```
|       BEFORE |        AFTER |
-------------------------------
|     Test One |    One, Test |
| Test Two One | Test Two One |
|  Test, Three |  Test, Three |
```

Comment: +1 for striping out the spaces then comparing the new length versus the original length to determine how many spaces were in the original string... definitely a good way to count characters in a string that I wasn't aware of!

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7720)**

```
DECLARE @Tests TABLE (
    Before VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Tests Values ('Test One')
INSERT INTO @Tests Values ('Test Two One')
INSERT INTO @Tests Values ('Test, Three')

SELECT
    Before,
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            -- If there is no comma...
            CHARINDEX(',', Before) = 0
            -- And if there is only one space... 
            AND CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(Before, LEN(Before) - 
                CHARINDEX(' ', Before))) = 0
        THEN 
            -- Then perform the swap.
            RIGHT(Before, LEN(Before) - CHARINDEX(' ', Before)) + ', ' 
            + LEFT(Before, CHARINDEX(' ', Before))
        -- Otherwise, retain the "before" value.
        ELSE Before
    END AS After
FROM @Tests
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take : Not the best as it uses quiet a number of string functions...

- Assumptions:

  1. That you only have two words ;)
  2. There is a space/ or ther character...
- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9dcc/3)

Code:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',name) splitposition,
SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',name)-1) firstword,
SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ',name), len(name)) lastword,
(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ',name), len(name)) +
', ' + SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',name)-1)) as swapped
from moneys;
```

Results:

```
| SPLITPOSITION | FIRSTWORD | LASTWORD |   SWAPPED |
----------------------------------------------------
|             5 |      test |      one |  one, test |
```

ps: I used an old table in sql server for the demo..

Comment: @AjitGoel please take a look at this. Simple select from your table if you have an existing table column that you are trying to perform this. If you want to write a function, you may still use the same or even better logic :)